# AppBar with AppBarUtils navigation not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, uinavigationbar, appbar

I have this bug in my solution:

**Exception**

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in AppBarUtils.dll
```

**XAML**

```
 <controls:Pivot Background="#FF10662B" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Black" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <abu:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger>
                    <abu:SwitchAppBarAction>
                        <abu:AppBar Id="0">
                            <abu:AppBar.MenuItems>
                                <abu:AppBarMenuItem Text="Załóż konto" Command="{Binding                        
                                 NavigateCommand,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </abu:AppBar.MenuItems> 

                            <abu:AppBarButton IconUri="{Binding AddButtonIcon}"
                                                    Text="Navigation" >
                                <ec:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="/LoginPage.xaml"/>
                            </abu:AppBarButton>

                        </abu:AppBar>

                    </abu:SwitchAppBarAction>
                </abu:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

             <--rest code with other pivots -->


</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Maybe I can use another way use navigation to page? How I can navigate to different page with mvvm?

Answer (score 1):

You can create ApplicationBar for certain pivot items of pivot page like this using id.If id =0,it will take automatically pivot Page(Item) 0 .By using this,you can choose which all AppBars has to be in whole pivot pages and in selective pivot pages(Items).

```
<phone:Pivot>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger>
            <appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger.SelectionMappings>
                <appBarUtils:SelectionMapping SourceIndex="0" TargetIndex="0"/>
            </appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger.SelectionMappings>

            <appBarUtils:SwitchAppBarAction>
                <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="0"   BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.home.png" Text="home" Command="{Binding HomeNavigationCommand}"/>
                </appBarUtils:AppBar>

                <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="1" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.home.png" Text="home" Command="{Binding HomeNavigationCommand}"/>
                </appBarUtils:AppBar>

                <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="2" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.home.png" Text="home" Command="{Binding HomeNavigationCommand}"/>
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.money.png" Text="collection" Command="{Binding CollectionPageCommand}"/>
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.check.rest.png" Text="ok" Command="{Binding OrderConfirmationButtonCommand}"/>
                </appBarUtils:AppBar>

                <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="3"  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton x:Name="ConfirmationAppBarButton" IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.cancel.rest.png" Text="cancel" Command="{Binding OrderCancelButtonCommand}"/>
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.check.rest.png" Text="ok" Command="{Binding OrderConfirmationButtonCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Model.EnableCheck,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </appBarUtils:AppBar>

            </appBarUtils:SwitchAppBarAction>
        </appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</phone:Pivot>
```

For navigation using mvvm,you can use messenger.

If you are using MVVM architecture,then you can pass navigationPage after registering using Messenger. Create a model class (say NavigateToPageMessage) with a string(say PageName) variable. You want to pass string from homepage.xaml to newpage.xaml,then in Homepage viewmodel  just send the message like this under the command you binded (say HomeNavigationCommand)

```
private void HomeNavigationCommandHandler()
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send(new NavigateToPageMessage {PageName = "newpage"});
        }
```

In the newpage Viewmodel,you should register the messenger like this,

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NavigateToPageMessage>(this, (action) => ReceiveMessage(action));

 private object ReceiveMessage(NavigateToPageMessage action)
        {
            var page = string.Format("/Views/{0}.xaml", action.PageName);           
            NavigationService.Navigate(new System.Uri(page,System.UriKind.Relative));
            return null;
        }
```

//Assuming your views are in View Folder